# How can have the while loop working properly?

Tags: java

```
public static int userInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int enteredValue = -8;
    while (enteredValue !=8) {
        try {
            enteredValue = scanner.nextInt();
            if (enteredValue < 0) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid interger entered");
            enteredValue = -8;
        }
        break;
    }
    scanner.nextLine();
    return enteredValue;
}
```

Comment: when I dont write break, it will keep giving infinite loop

Comment: What is the intention of this code? When is the loop supposed to end? Right now, without the `break`, it will keep asking until user enters `8`. With the `break`, it'll never loop, so you might as well not have one.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `while (enteredValue == -8)`, so it initially enters the loop, keeps looping if an exception is caught.

Comment: @billjamesdev True, removed that part. Thanks!

Comment: I think we need to stop guessing and wait for clarification.. Right now this code is the most elaborate `return 8` i've ever seen!

Comment: *when I dont write break, it will keep giving infinite loop* - works fine for me - it loops repeatedly asking the user to enter a number, unless they enter 8. No infinite loop though.. It asks for input and gives the user an opportunity to exit the loop on every pass. Try telling us what you want it to do

Comment: @CaiusJard, it's `return -8 if enteredValue < 0 else enteredValue` because of the `break`

Comment: @Steve ah.. I was going off the "when I don't write break" bit (i.e. removing the break ,as the author seemingly desires to do, turns it into `return 8`)

Comment: @fatunkazi Just add scanner.next(); inside catch block
You have infinite loop because invalid value (not Integer) still inside input buffer and you can`t read it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply, really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as billjamesdev suggests, the point is to get the user to enter a non-negative integer, the code can be made simpler.

None of that magic with -8 is needed, and

```
public static int userInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int enteredValue = -8; // just to get loop started
    while (enteredValue < 0) {
        try {
            enteredValue = scanner.nextInt();
            if (enteredValue < 0)
                System.out.println("Negative integer entered");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid integer entered"); 
            scanner.nextLine(); // clear input
       }
    }
    scanner.nextLine();
    return enteredValue;
}
```

Note: rather than throwing an exception on negative input, I chose to just report the error directly, since this allows me to use a more specific message.

A subtlety is that if the exception is thrown, then no assignment to `enteredValue` can have occurred, and therefore it is still negative, since it is unchanged from the top of the loop.

Using a do-while loop didn't seem to add much to readability, so I left it as a while-loop.

Comment: Now just enter something like string "asd" and you will get infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after you mentioned it above - thanks.